# Store Miscellaneous Data in DB Table Row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, row, separator

Let's assume I need to store some data of unknown amount within a database table. I don't want to create extra tables, because this will take more time to get the data. The amount of data can be different.

My initial thought was to store data in a `key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3` format, but the problem here is that some value can contain `;` in its body. What is the best separator in this case? What other methods can I use to be able to store various data in a single row?

The example content of the row is like `data=2012-05-14 20:07:45;text=This is a comment, but what if I contain a semicolon?;last_id=123456` from which I can then get through PHP an array with corresponding keys and values after correctly exploding row text with a seperator.

Comment: Your question is too vague.  Can you give some examples of what you want?  In general, you do not want to concatenate key value pairs into a field.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off storing each key-value pair as a separate row? That would sidestep the issue with the semicolon.

Comment: @andrewsi The issue here is that I don't know exact number of key=value pairs and if I create all the rows that would be too much unused space. I'm trying to compress everything in one row.

Comment: You haven't said why all this data has to be in a single row. I don't think you're going to get the kind of answers you're looking for until you do.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, for example I want to store some dates, short text, some id's etc. This would be like `data=2012-05-14 20:07:45;text=This is a comment, but what if I contain a semicolon?;last_id=123456`

Comment: If that's your only issue, use something like "|" to delimit the strings.  However, this data wants to be normalized.

Comment: Also: what are you going to be running this on, that you're that worried about unused space and the time taken for querying across multiple tables? If it's a web application, then you're not going to have to worry about performance issues until you're dealing with hundreds of thousands of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: You never ever store more than one information in only one field, **if you need to access them separately or search by one of them**. This has been discussed here quite a few times.

Assuming you allwas want to access the complete collection of information at once, I recommend to use the native serialization format of your development environment: e.g. if it is PHP, use `serialze()`.

If it is cross-plattform, JSON might be a way to go: Good JSON encoding/decoding libraries exist for something like all environments out there. The same is true for XML, but int his context the textual overhead of XML is going to bite a bit.

On a sidenote: Are you sure, that storing the data in additional tables is slower? You might want to benchmark that before finally deciding.

**Edit:**

After reading, that you use PHP: If you don't want to put it in a table, stick with `serialize()` / `unserialize()` and a `MEDIUMTEXT` field, this works perfectly, I do it all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As for the storing data in additional table - I am completely against it. There's too much work to do in case this data is changed often.

Comment: @DenisBobrovnikov - That rational doesn't make sense to me.  If you create a new table, where each key-value-pair is it's own record, you can now much more easily search for, access, analyse, and update any of those values.  If you stuff the values into a string, you need to extract the value you want from the string, check if it was there at all and increase complexity, margin for error and degrade performance.  I strongly recommend EugenRieck's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

EAV (*cringe*) is probably the best way to store arbitrary values like you want, but it sounds like you're firmly against additional tables for whatever reason. In light of that, you could just save the result of json_encode in the table. When you read it back, just json_decode to get it back into an array.

Keep in mind that if you ever need to search for anything in this field, you're going to have to use a SQL LIKE. If you **never** need to search this field or join it to anything, I suppose it's OK, but if you do, you've totally thrown performance out the window.

Answer (score -1):

it can be the quotes who separate them .

```
key1='value1';key2='value2';key3='value3'
```

if not like that , give your sql example and we can see how to do it.

Comment: Thanks. What if I fetch this data by <?php explode(';', $data)?> ? The semicolons within the quotes will too be considered as separators.

Comment: This is a SQL anti-pattern.  `EAV` or some other construct has enough difficulties to optimise, this suggestion is just pure bad practice.  Sorry, I have to down vote.

Comment: The quotes will not help you with `explode()`.

Comment: it doesnt help u the quotes with `explode`